# Insert Plus Signs and Add

Tags: mathematics, optimization, number-theory

If you take any integer (in base 10) and insert plus signs, "+", in between its digits (as few or as many as you like), and carry out the indicated sum, you will end up with a smaller number (unless you chose to insert none). If this resulting number is not a single digit, and you again perform on it the above operation, you are now likely to obtain a single digit.

It is known that at most three such operations are necessary to convert any number into a single digit.

**What is the smallest number that requires precisely those three steps?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is

> 289

Reasoning

> I went backwards.  Assuming the 4th (last) number is 1, 3rd is 10, 2nd is 19.

Then

> The three digit numbers like 667, 577, 478, 388, 289 all work.  199 does not because 1+99 = 100 which goes to 1, not 19.

In particular

> 289 ==> 2+8+9 =19 ==> 10 ==> 1 or
>  289 ==> 2+89 = 91 ==> 10 ==> 1 or
>  289 ==> 28+9 = 37 ==> 10 ==> 1

The 2nd number

> must be 19 when the digits of the 1st number is added individually.
>  why?  the most it could be otherwise with 3 digits is 27.  Between 1 and 27, the only number that adds to a 2 digit number (10) is 19.  We know that the minimum is 3 digits or less because 289 works.

And since

> 289 is the smallest number which adds to 19 AND has all of its iterations work, this must be the minimum number that works.

Comment: I wonder which are the next such numbers. Is the sequence of these numbers in the OEIS?.

Comment: @BernardoRecamánSantos v guvax gur svefg ahzoref bs gung frdhrapr ner 289, 298, 379, 388, 397, 469, 478, 487, 496, rgp. ohg v qbag frr vg va BRVF.